# Definite integral $\int \frac{1}{x} y(x) dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

How would one evaluate the definite integral $\int_a^b \frac{1}{x} y(x) dx$ where $y(x)$ is an unknown function of which only the values at the integration bounds $y(x=a) = y_a$ and $y(x=b) = y_b$? are known.

I have attempted using integration by parts:

$\int_a^b \frac{1}{x} y(x) dx = [y \ln(x)]_a^b - \int_a^b \ln(x) \frac{dy}{dx}dx$

but then I am not sure how to evaluate the rightmost integral. What is the proper technique to use here?

Comment: are you sure this have a closed solution? I don't think you can do nothing with no information about $y$.

Comment: Look at the case of $a=0$, $b=1$, $y_1(x)=x$ and $y_2(x)=x^2$. What can you conclude?

Comment: It should have a closed solution in terms of the values at y(a) and y(b). I am trying to follow the steps taken in a paper where they do obtain a solution of a problem of this form. Unfortunately the steps taken are omitted and they simply mention "after integrating from a to b".

Comment: @Gary I do not quite understand what you mean. What are $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$? Here I have just a single function $y(x)$ of which I know the values at the integration bounds but nothing else.

Comment: @tgv Follow the suggestion by Gary... The functions $y_1(x)=x$ and $y_2(x)=x^2$ have the same values at $x = 0,1$. If you could compute the integral just based on the values at $x = a,b$, you should have
$$\int_0^1 \frac 1x y_1(x) dx = \int_0^1 \frac 1x y_2(x) dx...$$

Comment: @Gary, maybe you could convert your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to compute $\int_a^b \frac{y(x)}{x}dx$ knowing only $y(a)$ and $y(b)$. Take the example of $a=0$, $b=1$. We can choose two different functions that have the same values at the endpoints, for example $y_1(x)=x$ and $y_2(x)=x^2$. Now if it is possible to determine $\int_0^1 \frac{y_1(x)}{x}dx$ and $\int_0^1 \frac{y_2(x)}{x}dx$ based solely on the values of $y_1$, $y_2$ at the endpoints, the two integrals must have the same value (since $y_1(0)=y_2(0)=0$ and $y_1(1)=y_2(1)=1$). But $\int_0^1 \frac{y_1(x)}{x}dx =1 \neq \frac{1}{2} =\int_0^1 \frac{y_2(x)}{x}dx$. In short, the value of the integral depends heavily on what happens *inside* the interval of integration.